# In C# , how to set English time zone when formating a DateTIme?

Tags: linux, shell, jar, apache-spark

private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
string startTime = formatter.format(DateTime.Now); //请求时间

Those are Java codes. Can you help me convert the Java codes to equaivlent（equal） C#（.net） codes？

I know to use DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z ") ,but the core problem is that I don't know how to set the time to English time.
I have struggled for half a day, and it's too difficult to me. who can give me a final result?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This ain't no free coding platform. Try it yourself and come back when you struggle.

Comment: Then use the [other `ToString` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to provide an `IFormatSpecifier`. Pass a `new CultureInfo("en-us")` for example to use US time formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a specific culture's formatting with `ToString()`, use the [`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload which allows you to pass a [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) as the second argument.

Since you wanted "English time", you could use this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

There's also `en-GB` and many more. For more culture names, see the list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx . On Windows 10, you can also use any valid BCP-47 tag.